# blade template, @yield at extended view

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I would like to define a section at the layout or at an include, such as:

```
/views/master.blade.php
@section('mysection')
    content here
@stop
@yield('content')
```

And be able to yield it at the view inheriting the layout:

```
/views/home.blade.php
@extends('master')
@section('content')
    @yield('mysection')
@stop
```

From what I've tested this doesn't work. Is there another way of doing this?

Some sections are not supposed to always render and also not in the same place as they are on the layout, so the yield method would do what I need.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to modify the master.blade.php as:

```
/views/master.blade.php
@section('mysection')
    content here
@show
@yield('content')
```